# How do I make my font bold with the GreenFoot API?

Tags: java, fonts, greenfoot

I have this font constructor written to make the font I want BOLD, however whenever I try to compile, it tells me the error `Cannot find symbol - variable BOLD`.

```
Font font = new Font("Arial",font.BOLD, 40);
```

These are the classes I'm importing:

```
import greenfoot.*;
import java.util.*;
import greenfoot.Font;
import java.lang.Class;
```

If anyone knows the probably quick fix it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Even after editing the capitalization the same error was given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the constructor incorrectly. Per the [documentation](https://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/Font.html):

> #### Constructor and Description
>
> `Font(java.lang.String name, boolean bold, boolean italic, int size)`
>
> Creates a font from the specified font name, size and style.

It should be like so (bold,  non-italic):

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", true, false, 40);
```

You were using the constructor incorrectly and attempt to access an instance variable that did not exist.